# Can pgpool-II balance PostgreSQL servers with multiple instances each?

Tags: postgresql, load-balancing, failover, pgpool

I have configured two PostgreSQL 9.5 instances in master-slave mode and could successfully configure PgPool-II for load balancing between them, and failover is just working fine (took me 2 weeks and lots of errors, but it finally worked).

My question now is: imagine that one PostgreSQL server has multiple instances, and the second server also has multiple instances, each instance paired between the two servers in many ports, each port for each instance (of course), and each of these instances configured for master-slave replication. Is it possible to configure load balance and failover for all these instances with only one PgPool installation, or should I configure one PgPool for each PostgreSQL instance?

Thanks in advance,

Igor Felix

Comment: Maybe the best question would be: Can one pgpool-II instance balance PostgreSQL servers with multiple instances each? ;)

Comment: After many days of search, I am beginning to think that it is not possible. Since the solution (for now) is many instances in one server, I am guessing that PgPool-II will be abandoned. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have not found anything at Google, no one answered anything, and also nothing was found in the source code, I answer this question as not possible, or one pgpool for each postgres cluster.